# Instagram and iOS. get photo with a lot of likes with current user

Tags: ios, api, instagram

I am using Instagram api

My query is

```
api.instagram.com/v1/users/[USER_ID]/media/recent?count=3818
```

I get only 33 photos that is ordered by date

But,I need to load all the users photo which has more likes

what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pagination.See http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ for information on pagination. You need to subsequentially step through the result pages, each time requesting the next part with the next_url that the result specifies in the pagination object.

From instagram

> **pagination**
>
> Sometimes you just can't get enough. For this reason, we've provided a
>   convenient way to access more data in any request for sequential data.
>   Simply call the url in the next_url parameter and we'll respond with
>   the next set of data.
>
> {
>       ...
>       "pagination": {
>           "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/puppy/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d&max_id=13872296",
>           "next_max_id": "13872296"
>       } }
>
> On views where pagination is present, we also support the "count"
>   parameter. Simply set this to the number of items you'd like to
>   receive. Note that the default values should be fine for most
>   applications - but if you decide to increase this number there is a
>   maximum value defined on each endpoint.